# Best Practice Restful API Naming Conventions

Tags: laravel, rest, api

We have a currently a large API which serves many different clients and apps. As we want to move forward, we are in discussion to split up our API endpoint into dedicated ones.

Our base-URL is like this `api.domain.com/{apiVersion}`

With this, we serve for example our main App and an Reseller App:

Users Endpoint: `api.domain.com/v1/users`

Resellers Endpoint: `api.domain.com/v1/resellers/sales`

Our Idea is to change that either into:

`api.domain.com/users`

`api.domain.com/resellers/sales`

or into:

`users.domain.com`

`resellers.domain.com/sales`

I didn't find any good best practices on that, so maybe some has an interesting link or some opinion on that matter.

My preference would be `api.domain.com/...`, as everything is an API and you dont have to change the base url, but the second one makes it more **dedicated** imho.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to review [Roy Fielding on Versioning, Hypermedia, and REST](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning/).

> Unfortunately, versioning interface names only manages change for the API owner’s sake. That is a myopic view of interface design: one where the owner’s desire for control ignores the customer’s need for continuity.
>
> ....
>
> It is always possible for some unexpected reason to come along that requires a completely different API, especially when the semantics of the interface change or security issues require the abandonment of previously deployed software. My point was that there is no need to anticipate such world-breaking changes with a version ID. **We have the hostname for that**. What you are creating is not a new version of the API, but a new system with a new brand.

*(emphasis added)*

You can also review Fielding's [slides from Evolve '13](https://www.slideshare.net/evolve_conference/201308-fielding-evolve/31)